# Excel VBA Change Color Of value on USERFORM

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how can I change the color of value or Text-box depending the value. example if the get "F" I want this value turn RED or the Text-box either way on the User-form.

[Here is a example of where I want to use it or how I would like to use it.](https://app.box.com/s/5jmg8m4rz84g9r17ohyy)

```
Private Sub cmdAceptar_click()
Dim n1 As Double, n2 As Double, n3 As Double, n4 As Double
Dim promedio As Integer

n1 = Val(txtn1): n2 = Val(txtn2)
n3 = Val(txtn3): n4 = Val(txtn4)
promedio = CInt((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4)
txtPromedio = Str(promedio)

If promedio >= 90 And promedio <= 100 Then
    txtPuntuacion = "A"
ElseIf promedio >= 80 And promedio <= 89 Then
    txtPuntuacion = "B"
ElseIf promedio >= 70 And promedio <= 79 Then
    txtPuntuacion = "C"
ElseIf promedio >= 60 And promedio <= 69 Then
    txtPuntuacion = "D"
ElseIf promedio >= 0 And promedio <= 59 Then
    txtPuntuacion = "F"
Else: MsgBox "Error de datos", vbCritical, "Mensaje"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Color of the TextBox to Red:

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255,0,0)
```

Change Text Color of the TextBox to Red:

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(255,0,0)
```

UPDATE: Full solution (assuming **txtPuntuacion** is the TextBox):

```
Private Sub cmdAceptar_click()
    Dim n1 As Double, n2 As Double, n3 As Double, n4 As Double
    Dim promedio As Integer
    Dim sGrade As String

    n1 = Val(txtn1): n2 = Val(txtn2)
    n3 = Val(txtn3): n4 = Val(txtn4)
    promedio = CInt((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4)
    txtPromedio = Str(promedio)

    Select Case promedio
        Case 90 To 100: sGrade = "A"
        Case 80 To 89:  sGrade = "B"
        Case 70 To 79:  sGrade = "C"
        Case 60 To 69:  sGrade = "D"
        Case 0 To 59:   sGrade = "F"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error de datos", vbCritical, "Mensaje"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    txtPuntuacion.Value = sGrade
    If sGrade = "F" Then
        txtPuntuacion.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        txtPuntuacion.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx patricK but this solutions is permanent, i want in case that if get some value (as "F") turn red but if get other value (as "B") keep the black color

Comment: I was purely point you the direction to change color of the text box/text. Add another `If` block for `txtPuntuacion` to switch between Black/Red.